# pyinstaller does not find hidden import for editable module python-pptx

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-import, python-pptx

I am using `pyinstaller` `v1.13.0` to create an executable for my application on a Windows computer. The application uses the `python-pptx` `v1.6.21` package, and as I intend to make local modifications to that package, I cloned the source and installed it to a separate folder using

```
pip install --editable <base-folder-of-pptx>
```

from within my current virtual environment. Here is the console output after installing `python-pptx` as "editable":

```
(venv) c:\projects\test>pip list
Package                   Version      Editable project location
------------------------- ------------ -----------------------------------------------------------
altgraph                  0.17.3
...
python-pptx               0.6.21       C:\libs\_Python\python-ppt
...
```

For `pyinstaller`, I use a `build.spec` file to set necessary specifications:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

import gooey
gooey_root = os.path.dirname(gooey.__file__)
gooey_languages = Tree(os.path.join(gooey_root, 'languages'), prefix = 'gooey/languages')
gooey_images = Tree(os.path.join(gooey_root, 'images'), prefix = 'gooey/images')

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['gui.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\projects\\test\\build\\test'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[
                '__future__',
                'argparse',
                ...
                'pptx',
                ...
                ],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False,
             )

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

options = [('u', None, 'OPTION')]

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          options,
          gooey_languages,
          gooey_images,
          name='test',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True,
          icon=os.path.join(gooey_root, 'images', 'program_icon.ico'))
```

In order to generate an executable application, I type:

```
pyinstaller build.spec
```

Which results in loads of INFO messages but ONE error message concerning not being able to localize the `python-pptx` package:

```
293 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.13.0
293 INFO: Python: 3.11.5
307 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0
320 INFO: checking Tree
323 INFO: checking Tree
325 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
...
11694 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'helpers'
11697 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'isoweek'
11702 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'logging_wrapper'
11702 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'model'
11703 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'pptx'
11703 ERROR: Hidden import 'pptx' not found
11704 INFO: Processing module hooks...
11704 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lxml.etree.py' from 'C:\\projects\\test\\envs\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
12028 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-charset_normalizer.py' from 'C:\\projects\\test\\envs\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
12229 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lxml.isoschematron.py' from 'C:\\projects\\test\\envs\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
12427 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py' from 'C:\\projects\\test\\envs\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
12501 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lxml.objectify.py' from 'C:\\projects\\test\\envs\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
12520 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
...
27401 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 7 resource with 18749 bytes
27406 INFO: Copying 0 resources to EXE
27406 INFO: Embedding manifest in EXE
27407 INFO: Updating manifest in c:\projects\test\build\project\dist\project.exe.notanexecutable
27408 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 1 language 0
27413 INFO: Appending PKG archive to EXE
27439 INFO: Fixing EXE headers
27683 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Now, I uninstall the editable `python-pptx` package and re-install it from PyPi e.g. by using

```
pip install "python-pptx=0.6.21"
```

:

```
(venv) c:\projects\test>pip list
Package                   Version      Editable project location
------------------------- ------------ -----------------------------------------------------------
altgraph                  0.17.3
...
python-pptx               0.6.21
...
```

The error message about not finding the package is gone and the created application runs fine:

```
282 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.13.0
282 INFO: Python: 3.11.5
295 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0
308 INFO: checking Tree
310 INFO: checking Tree
313 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
...
13506 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'helpers'
13507 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'isoweek'
13517 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'model'
13518 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'pptx'
14362 INFO: Processing module hooks...
14364 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lxml.etree.py' from 'C:\\projects\\test\\envs\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
14729 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-charset_normalizer.py' from 'C:\\projects\\test\\envs\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
15020 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lxml.isoschematron.py' from 'C:\\projects\\test\\envs\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
15268 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py' from 'C:\\projects\\test\\envs\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
...
31418 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 7 resource with 18749 bytes
31423 INFO: Copying 0 resources to EXE
31423 INFO: Embedding manifest in EXE
31425 INFO: Updating manifest in c:\projects\test\build\project\dist\project.exe.notanexecutable
31425 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 1 language 0
31430 INFO: Appending PKG archive to EXE
31472 INFO: Fixing EXE headers
31726 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

As I think, the described effect is of general nature (not specific to the package `python-pptx` I used), I would be happy if someone could try to help setting up a configuration similar to mine which allows to use `editable` packages.

Any ideas?